# Laravel - My rediction is not working perfectly

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel App, I did a rediction after login.

When I open my browser or my localhost and I write : **www.domaine.com** , I got a redirection to my menu **www.domaine.com/menu.**

Then when I logout and I login again, I have to redirect to **www.domaine.com/hello** as I want it.

My **www.domaine.com/hello** is a 10s video that redicrect  to **www.domaine.com/menu** after watching

For redirection, I just changed redirection in LoginController.php

Code : 
LoginController : `

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
protected $redirectTo = '/hello';`
```

Route :

```
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: you canr provider some code??

Comment: sorry, but its kinda confusing.. so you had a redirection on `LoginController.php` set to `/hello`? and you redirected the user once 10s passed on the hello page into `/menu`? the problem is, you want the user only get `/hello` once in their lifetime?

Comment: Can you provide your route.list and your controller?

Comment: @bagus, yes this is my configuration, the problem is i'm not having the redicrection to /hello the first time i open the browser

Comment: Yes, i provided code, please check my eddited post

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is about `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware check it , it has another redirect if you authenticate .

lemme know if your problem dosen't solved!

Comment: Hello si rthanku for ur interest, what i exactly need to check please ?

Comment: check this middleware run or not because this middleware redirect you

Comment: check this line return redirect('/home');

Comment: Please check out my code in my eddited post, i don't have a return reidrect() in my code ...

Comment: this problem happen when you are login and refresh the page or when you are logout and login again?

Comment: When im logout and i open the siteweb it's not working 
When im login and i logout and then i login again it works.

Comment: with witch middleware you protect your route?  I think you can fix your problem with custom auth middleware !